# reading lines with variable numbers of fields from a file in c#

Tags: c#

How do you read the lines one by one if their fields are uneven and you need to know when it ends.

For example:

```
A;B;C;D 
E;F;G;H;J
```

'A' is a person and 'B' , 'C' and 'D' are his friends.It goes the same for the second line I wrote.I know I could just write it with an even number of fields but I think this is a neater way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing so far, and what problems are you having with your solution?

Comment: Please include details of what you've tried, and specific code related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two functions that make this really easy: `StreamReader.ReadLine` and `String.Split`.

You use `StreamReader.ReadLine` to get the entire line of text:

```
string lineOfInput = reader.ReadLine();
```

Then, you can split on the semicolons to get all your "fields":

```
string[] fields = lineOfInput.Split(';');
```

`fields[0]` will contain the "person" and the rest, his "friends".

See [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readline) and [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Any comment from the downvoter? I'm happy to look at improving my answer if you feel there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are deceptively simple. See this question, [Simple csv reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558029/simple-csv-reader/3558785), for some details.

But I'd just use Sebastien Lorion's *Fast CSV Reader* from CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

All you've got to do is set the correct field separator and you're good to go. It's fast, it works well. It implements `IDataReader`, so it acts like a normal .Net data reader implementation.